# %left and %right in yacc

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction, yacc, operator-precedence

```
{%
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
%}
  
%token ID NUM IF THEN LE GE EQ NE OR AND ELSE

%right '='
%left AND OR
%left '<' '>' LE GE EQ NE
%left '+''-'
%left '*''/'
%right UMINUS
%left '!'

%%
```

The code mentioned above is part of the yacc for a simple `IF ELSE` program.

What do `%right` and `%left` mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%left` and `%right` specify the [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of an operator. The associativity of an operation determines which of two operations of the same precedence level is carried out first.

Suppose we have the grammar rules:

```
exp ::= exp + exp
exp ::= ID
```

and suppose we have to parse the expression x+y-z. You see, as the precedence level of plus and minus is the same, this expression can be interpreted as (x+y)-z or x+(y-z). This does not seem like a big deal, but it introduces an ambiguity into the grammar.

Parsing issues and theory aside, suppose we're parsing the expression. 6+5-7, and suppose that our language can only work with natural numbers, and throws an exception when underflow occurs. The result of `(6+5)-7` (4) will not be not equal to `6+(5-7)` (exception), so we won't be able to predict the result -- unless we define the evaulation order by specifying the associativity of the operators. Also consider the case of expressions like `f()+g()+h()`, when the operands are functions which may have side effects.

Comment: Also as `%left '*' '/'` is written below `%left '+' '-'`, `* and /` gets more precedence than `+ and -`

Answer (score 28):

I know this is an old question but in case some one else is looking for this information :

`%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc`, defines how yacc will solve repetition of operators. In case you have:

```
1 + 2 + 3
```

both operators have the same precedence level ( they are the same :) ), in this case yacc can solve:

```
// using %left
(1 + 2) + 3
```

or:

```
// using %right
1 + (2 + 3)
```

and finally:

```
//using %nonassoc
1 + 2 + 3 is considered illegal and a syntax error!
```

you can read more in [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Precedence-Decl.html).